# How does SelectContentControlsByTitle and .item() work?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

[English is not my first language]

I am developing a Word document where the user inputs information in content controls rich text boxes. These inputs are then displayed as choices in several drop down lists (combo boxes) further down.

It looks as follow:

---

Locations:
[Insert location 1 here]
[Insert location 2 here]
[Insert location 3 here]
[Insert location 4 here]
 
[Insert location 5 here]
 

(The CC title for each one is "LocationMenu")
(The CC tag for each one has to be "Header")

---

The user may use one or many locations.

I am writing a loop that will check how many content controls have been filled, and then will use the filled one as list entries for the drop down list. My plan was to use the same TITLE for each content control in my initial menu, and loop through the .SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu").Item(x).

However...

Why is it that when I try this:

```
MsgBox (ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu").Item(2).Range.Text)
```

I get [Insert location 3 here] and not [Insert location 2 here]?

When I try:

```
MsgBox (ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu").Item(1).Range.Text)
```

I get [Insert location 2 here] and not [Insert location 1 here]?

(It's not a array-starts-at-0 issue either)

**Could someone give me more details on how to use the "item()" portion of the code?** People seems to work around it by putting a unique title for each content control and leaving the .item(x) at .item(1)... but that won't work for what I am trying to do... How do we use .item(x)???

thank you so much
 

 
 
 
Here are the pages I consulted, but did not find an answer:
 

 
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-50894.html
 

 
http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/interactive_userforms.html

The msdn.microsoft.com stuff did not help.
Could not find the answer of Stack Overflow either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About the Item property, and iterating collection types

By convention, `Item` is a special `Property Get` member defined in collection object types that [can/should] contain object references.

If you could view the definition of that property getter, you would see something like this:

```
Public Property Get Item(ByVal index As Variant) As Variant
Attribute Item.VB_Description = "Gets or sets the element at the specified index."
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    'implementation
End Property
```

That `Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0` hidden attribute sets the COM type member's `DispId` property to 0, making it the class' *default member*.

In other words this:

```
Debug.Print myCollection.Item(1).Range.Text
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
Debug.Print myCollection(1).Range.Text
```

The exact specifics of how an `Item` property works with a given index, is implementation-specific, i.e. depends on how the collection class is implemented.

But one thing all collection classes have in common, is a hidden `[_NewEnum]` property with a `VB_UserMemId = -4` hidden attribute, which tells VB6/VBA to use that method to get an *enumerator* for iterating that collection.

That's how collections can be iterated with a `For Each` loop.

And it's VERY efficient. Like, ~27 times faster than iterating a collection by index with a `For` loop.

Use it!

```
Dim ctrl As ContentControl
For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu")
    Debug.Print ctrl.Range.Text
Next
```

---

#### Your problem (and its solution)

Now, the problem is that you *think* you're iterating dropdown items, but you're really iterating `ContentControl` items, and what `.Range.Text` is returning is whatever the current value is in each of these controls (i.e. the `ActiveDocument` contains more than just one dropdown content control titled "LocationMenu").

If you want to iterate the dropdown values, you need to look at the `ContentControl.DropdownListEntries` collection:

```
Dim ctrl As ContentControl
For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu")
    Dim ddItem As ContentControlListEntry
    For Each ddItem In ctrl.DropdownListEntries
        Debug.Print ddItem.Text, ddItem.Value
    Next
Next
```

Comment: thank you, it solved my first problem!  I used the following:  `Dim ctrl As ContentControl
    For Each ctrl In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("LocationMenu")
        If ctrl.ShowingPlaceholderText = False Then
            objCCDList.DropdownListEntries.Add ctrl.Range.Text
        End If
    Next`  The issue I now have is that my dropdownlist is not in the same order as the content control (Location Menu).    Where I enter [item1],[item2],[item3],[item4],[item5]  I get as drop down menu [item3],[item1],[item4],[item2],[item5]... Any advice to keep them in the same order? thx

Comment: Collections normally iterate their items in the same order they were added in. A [`ContentControlListEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/contentcontrollistentry-object-word) object has an `Index` property that should give you that order - per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/contentcontrollistentry-index-property-word) that property is read-write, so you can reorder them at will.